# Catch async exception in correct context

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

When throwing an an error in an async call, the error is thrown after the `tryAjax()` context is gone, therefore never reaching my catch clause.

Is there a way to correctly catch a non synchronous exception?

```
function tryAjax(){
     try{
      didItWork(); 
     }
     catch(e){
       // Do something else
     }
    }

function didItWork(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (res, status, xhr)
            { 
               // Do something
            },
            error: function (e)
            {
                throw new Error('Canvas video not loaded');                
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: My example converting the promise rejection into an exception doesn't work, I've removed it. It doesn't work because, as I flagged up, control has already moved out of the `try/catch` before you throw it. I've removed it from the answer, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to correctly catch a non synchronous exception?

By the time the exception has occurred, control has already moved on and is no longer within your `try/catch`. Also, as you've discovered, jQuery catches and suppresses exceptions from within the `error` callback.

In this specific situation, the usual thing is to have `didItWork` accept a callback or return a promise, and call that callback or resolve/reject that promise with either the value you want (success) or a flag value indicating failure.

Here's a promise example:

```
function tryAjax(){
    didItWork()
        .done(function(data) {
            // All good, use `data`
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            // Failed, details in `err`
        });
}

function didItWork(){
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (res, status, xhr)
        { 
           d.resolveWith(res);
        },
        error: function (e)
        {
            d.rejectWith(new Error('Canvas video not loaded'));
        }
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```

Comment: Trying to implement this. BTW, isn't jquery's ajax function already a deferred? Will implementing the promise myself have added value?

Comment: @Skarlinski: `ajax` returns a promise (well, it returns a `jqXHR`, which is an XHR with promise stuff mixed in). Implementing your own just lets you control what it's resolved/rejected with.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this :  ( using deferred objects)

```
function tryAjax(){

  didItWork().fail(function (e){  // Do something specific})
             .done(function(a,b,c){//all ok}); 
}

function didItWork(){
     return   $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (res, status, xhr)
            { 

            },
            error: function (e)
            {
               //something general           
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a method upon any error in asynchronous calls like AJAX

```
 function didItWork(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (res, status, xhr)
        { 
           // Do something
        },
        error: function (e)
        {
            logError(e);               
        }
    });
    };
 }

 function logError(e)
 {
     //Perform activity related to error handling
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that this way I lose the ability to use catching exceptions as part of a control flow.

Comment: If you are worried about losing the control flow, try using the AJAX synchronously by setting async property to false.